# Wikipedia all persons URI

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Does Wikipedia have any dump with URIs only for Persons?

If not is it possible somehow to create it? (not using DBPedia SPARQL - just pure Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only meaningful URI for Wikipedia biographies is the Wikidata item ID. You can get a list simply looking for statements [is: human](https://tools.wmflabs.org/autolist/autolist1.html?q=claim[31:5]) (about 3 millions items, this includes Wikipedia in all languages).

If you want to use only MediaWiki API (for which there are [many libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code)), you can for instance look for entities mentioning Q5 and then filter by those which actually have it as object of a P31 statement:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=backlinks&bltitle=Q5&limit=1&props=title → `{"pageid":136,"ns":0,"title":"Q23"}` → https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&property=P31&entity=Q23 → `{"value":{"entity-type":"item","numeric-id":5},"type":"wikibase-entityid"}}` → OK, this is one.

("Pure Wikipedia" is not a thing, for instance all the images are stored on Wikimedia Commons; similarly, data is now stored on Wikidata. I assume you meant "pure Wikimedia projects" or "pure MediaWiki".)